# How can I store client side data from localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to store Locale data and save it on the server as a .txt or .json how could I go about doing that

Comment: you will need a serverside language. What can you use?

Comment: @epascarello I don't know any, but what ever is the simplest im willing to learn

Answer (score 0):

You need some client-side code that loads your data from local storage. That could look like this:

```
// get data from local storage
var myLocale = storage.getItem('yourKeyNameHere');

// send data to server
xhttp.open("PUT", "/path-to-backend/locale", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("locale=" + myLocale);
```

You also need a server that offers some kind of API to store that data. You might want to look into `node.js` with `express` to build a REST-style API or something similar. The server is responsible for storing the data as a file.

I would recomend to use a proper database instead of storing to a file though. You might want to look into the topics `SQL-databases`, for example `postgresql`.

Comment: I am using glitch to store the website, so I have the option to use a node app, or a sq lite server